# How to allocate memory for a static n-dimensional array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

What is the best way to allocate memory for an n-dimensional array in c++ at runtime? I am trying to read a matrix of values from a file, and depending on which file I read, the matrix could be any size. However, once the matrix is created, its size is static.

Since I don't know at compile-time what the size will be, I can't define it as `int[a][b]`, so I was experimenting with using pointers to pointers like `int**`, but when I declare `int** arr; arr[0][0] = 1` I get an error. I've experimented with other solutions as well. For example, I tried using one of the answers to [Determine array size in constructor initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751878/determine-array-size-in-constructor-initializer), using `int* arr; arr = new int[a]`, but it doesn't seem to work once I try to use it for two dimensions. Granted, I could be using it incorrectly, but the following block of code gives me a segfault:

```
int** arr;
(*arr) = new int[a];
```

edit: And of course, right after I ask the question, I find something semi-suitable in [Need help regarding Dynamic Memory Allocation for two dimensional arrays in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943776/need-help-regarding-dynamic-memory-allocation-for-two-dimensional-arrays-in-c?rq=1). I'd prefer not to do it this way, but it's definitely doable.

Comment: You could also just allocate it in a single array and access it using indices. like `index = x * width + y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do it something like this (stolen from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)):

```
int** ary = new int*[sizeX];
for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; ++i)
    ary[i] = new int[sizeY];
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
int *ary = new int[sizeX*sizeY];

// ary[i][j] is then rewritten as
ary[i*sizeY+j]
```

It might remove the headache of pointer indirection.